# Dell G3 having issue while booting with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd, 19.04

I have purchased a new [Dell G3 Laptop](https://www.croma.com/dell-g3-15-579-core-i7-8th-gen-windows-10-gaming-laptop-16-gb-1-tb-hdd-+-256-gb-ssd-4-gb-graphics-39-62-cm-black-/p/212378) and this system is provided with Windows 10 and when I removed Windows and installed Ubuntu in different ways, it was unable to boot and only got the following error:

> No Bootable device found. Please press any key to reboot.

What I did was:

1. I installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode.
2. I removed the HDD and added an additional SSD together with the existing SSD and I'm unable to boot with both disks.
3. I removed the extra SSD and tried booting with the existing SSD only and got the same error.
4. I made a bootable with RUFUS and installed Ubuntu 19.04 and it worked but it hangs every time while booting
5. I was also **unable to install with partitions** and then I had to go with **erase disk and install Ubuntu** option.

*How do I get Ubuntu installed on this machine?*

Comment: Can you please [see me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)?

Comment: @Fabby Do I need to create a new chat with you?

Comment: @Fabby, Can we discuss the issue now, I have the same issue with Dell Laptop

Comment: Sorry, I just started a new job: no time now.  **:-(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer for this.

First of all, I didn't need Rufus tool for bootable, StsratUp disk worked fine.

I created a partition of EFI file system **(Praimary)** 150 MB and other 5 partitions with **something else** option as required, mentioned below:

**/boot(Praimary), Swap(Praimary), /home(Logical), /opt(Logical), / (Praimary)**

And installed the Ubuntu, it worked.when

If you have 2 HDD or SSD then you need to select the disk for boot loader while installing.

All issue was that Dell systems don't provide the boot option when installing Ubuntu without EFI file system and it goes to Testing Mode.

Thanks to @Fabby:)